# Is it possible to do Continuous Integration with Postman using GoCD

Tags: postman, go-cd

Currently, I am exploring postman for API automation and I am stuck with continuous integration process.
Is it possible to do Continuous Integration with Postman using  GoCD.
I am only getting the documentation for CI with Jenkins and Postman.

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have written a script which covers my all test cases and have imported the parameters from the CSV file to run the script for multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GoCD to add about any command line task

https://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/configuration/admin_add_task.html

If you are using postman collections and `newman` for running these API tests you can configure GoCD to use the same commands used on jenkins (like on their blog)

http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/09/03/how-to-write-powerful-automated-api-tests-with-postman-newman-and-jenkins/

which is

`newman -c jenkins_demo.postman_collection --exitCode 1`